# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm trying to deploy my web app in Tomcat server locally and it's very simple Keycloak authentication app but i'm getting below error even after deleting all local repositories in this path ( .m2\repository\org\hibernate ) Then I done mvn clean install and tried to re-deploy again

Error Message:

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getBuilderFromIssuerIfPossible(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:83)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.fromIssuerLocation(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/security/oauth2/client/registration/ClientRegistration$Builder;

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations
```

here's my code :

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login();
        }
}
```

**UPDATED POM File :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.baeldung.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>E-Services-Portal</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
             </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
                <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>/sample/servlet/container/deploy/directory</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**NOTE : I'm using Spring 2.2.2**

Answer (score 1):

You have some duplicate dependencies and you're mixing up the old Spring Security OAuth project with the new Spring Security 5 OAuth support. Start by removing all security-related artifacts:

- spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client
- spring-security-config
- spring-security-oauth2
- spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure
- spring-security-core

Add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This will bring in the correct versions of spring-security-core and spring-security-config, among other dependencies.

Also add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't but still getting the same error, do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: How odd; is there any way to see your full POM?

Comment: In your POM, you do properly open the <relativePath/>?

Comment: this tag is closed , i haven't used it at all

Answer (score 1):

After reading OAuth2 document I resolved this issue by adding "autoconfigure" dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/